# Matlab code for computing index of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I need help to make Matlab code for computing index of matrix.

> The index of matrix $A$ is the least non negative integer $k$ such
>   that $\operatorname{rank}(A^{k+1}) = \operatorname{rank}(A^k)$.

If it is not possible to make Matlab code for this problem. What other ways can I use to find the index of matrix.

Please help me. I would be very much grateful to you.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the rank of a matrix? Do you know how to take the power of a matrix?

Comment: @Listing Ya, i know about all this. But do I have to compute power and rank every time to find index?

Comment: What is $k$ if $A$ has full rank? What is $k$ if it doesn't?

Comment: I guess for small matrices a simple loop would suffice. For big matrices (>10000 elem.) I have no clue, there's probably a good routine written somewhere (if not in matlab itself) that takes all those pesky instability issues into account.

Comment: @GPerez Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me code for small matrices? Thanks

Comment: @mathscrazy  Maybe I'm wrong, but as far as I can see, taking the power k does not change the rank of a matrix as long as k is finite. Where did you get that definition from? Do you have an example of a matrix of given index?

Comment: @A.Donda http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix

Comment: @GPerez, thanks! I didn't think of non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Is it practically useful for your intended application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new to this topic, so any critical reading of this answer would be appreciated – but I think one can do without looping over powers.

Every square matrix $A$ has a Jordan normal (or canonical) form $J =$

[image: Jordan normal form]

where $\lambda_i$, $i = 1 \ldots n$, are the eigenvalues of $A$, and all entries  shown as blank are zero. Since $J$ is related to $A$ by a similarity transformation, $J = P^{-1} A P$, and this extends to integer powers, $J^k = P^{-1} A^k P$, it holds
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\rank(A^k) = \rank(J^k).
$$

$J$ has a block-diagonal form, where the size of each Jordan block corresponds to the algebraic multiplicity $a_i$ of the respective eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. The total rank of $J$ is therefore the sum of the ranks of the Jordan blocks. Blocks with $\lambda_i \neq 0$ are of full rank, with $\lambda_i = 0$ of rank $a_i - 1$:
$$
\rank(J) = \sum_{\lambda_i \neq 0} a_i + \sum_{\lambda_i = 0} (a_i - 1).
$$

The powers $J^k$ also have block-diagonal form, where each block of $J^k$ is the $k$th power of the corresponding block of $J$. Full-rank blocks remain of full rank under finite powers $k$, while blocks with $\lambda_i = 0$ are nilpotent matrices of degree $a_i$ whose rank decreases with increasing $k$ until it reaches 0. Therefore:
$$
\rank(J^k) = \sum_{\lambda_i \neq 0} a_i + \sum_{\lambda_i = 0} \max(a_i - k, 0)
$$

The rank of $J^k$ and with it $A^k$ therefore decreases with increasing $k$ until the power of each Jordan block with $\lambda_i = 0$ has reached $a_i$. Consequently, the **index of $A$** is the maximum of the degrees of the nilpotent blocks of $J$, or

$$
\mathrm{index} (A) = \max_{\lambda_i = 0} ~ a_i .
$$

---

Matlab implementation using `jordan` from the *Symbolic Math Toolbox*:

```
J = jordan(A);
d = diag(J);                            % diagonal
sd = diag(J, 1);                        % superdiagonal
lambda = d([sd ; 0] == 0);              % eigenvalues
a = diff([0 ; find([sd ; 0] == 0)]);    % arithmetic multiplicities
index = max(a(lambda == 0));
```

Note however that this procedure is numerically problematic. Almost all square matrices are diagonalizable, which means a small numeric error in the representation of a non-diagonalizable matrix will often make it diagonalizable (see [TMW's text about the Jordan Canonical Form](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jordan-canonical-form.html)). Since the rank of a diagonalizable matrix does not change under finite powers $k$, its index is 1. All of this means that the index of a matrix is not a numerically stable property. It is no mistake that the function `jordan`, though it also works with numerical matrices, is included with Matlab's *symbolic* math functions.

A related problem is that the code above uses a comparison of eigenvalues with zero. This might be fixed to some degree by using a finite threshold, as in the following code (adapted from `rank.m`):

```
tol = max(size(A)) * eps(max(lambda));
index = max(a(abs(lambda) < tol));
```

Answer (score 2):

Naïve proposal: (Only recommended for small, stable matrices):

```
k = rank(A); 
index = 0;
A_copy = A;
A = A*A_copy;
aux = rank(A);
while(aux == k)
    index = index+1;
    k = rank(A);
    A = A*A_copy;
    aux = rank(A);
end
```

Where the final result is `index`. I hurried this, so any corrections will be welcomed.

Comment: i tried but some errors are coming.

Comment: hmm what does the error say?

Comment: I am getting this error ''Error: File: Untitled6.m Line: 7 Column: 11
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.''  (7 Column: 11 : while(aux = k))

Comment: Ha! The programmer's bane! It's fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I want to know whether your code will work for random and Hilbert matrices?

Comment: I didn't know what Hilbert matrices were, but upon searching it seems they are the canonical example of a badly conditioned matrix... the outlook is grim. Knowing this I wouldn't trust the code one bit. Although, if you can find routines for effectively computing powers of Hilbert matrices, and calculating their rank, then just substitute those into the code and then it should work perfectly. As for random matrices I'd make the code issue a warning if the detected matrix is nearly singular.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :)